How to make a composable that displays the lyrics of a song with chords above the words?
I have this json object:
{
    "number": "060",
    "audio": false,
    "chord": false,
    "code": "each_step_of_the_way",
    "chordUrl": null,
    "name": "EACH STEP OF THE WAY",
    "description": null,
    "mainChord": "F",
    "audioUrl": "/files/en/only_believe/audios/060.mp3",
    "songBook": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ONLY BELIEVE",
        "code": "only_believe",
        "userId": 3,
        "hidden": false,
        "addedBy": "SYSTEM",
        "description": null,
        "languageId": 2,
        "isDraft": false,
        "version": "v0.0.1",
        "createdAt": "2023-10-15T23:22:12.485+00:00",
        "updatedAt": "2023-10-15T23:22:12.485+00:00",
        "language": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "English",
            "code": "en",
            "createdAt": null,
            "updatedAt": null
        }
    },
    "author": null,
    "language": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "English",
        "code": "en",
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null
    },
    "verses": [
        {
            "id": 17371,
            "verseOrder": 1,
            "orderToShow": 1,
            "isRefrain": false,
            "line": "I'm [G]following Jesus, [C]One step at [D]a time;",
            "songId": 4008,
            "createdAt": "2023-10-15T23:22:12.594+00:00",
            "updatedAt": "2023-10-15T23:22:12.594+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 17372,
            "verseOrder": 2,
            "orderToShow": 2,
            "isRefrain": false,
            "line": "[G]The pathway is [C]narrow, But He leads [D]me on;",
            "songId": 4008,
            "createdAt": "2023-10-15T23:22:12.595+00:00",
            "updatedAt": "2023-10-15T23:22:12.595+00:00"
        }
    ]
}

With jetpack compose I want to parse it and get this result:
 EACH STEP OF THE WAY

           G             C       D
1. I'm following Jesus, One step at a time;

    G               C                  D
2. The pathway is narrow, But He leads me on;

No matter the screen size.
I tried with this code but it's not working:
fun getSongs(): MutableList<Line> {
    val verses = listOf(
        "Я[A] так слаб, но силен Т[Bm]ы,$ У[E7]держать меня вда[A]л[E7]и$",
        "О[A]т всег[A7]о, что мне вред[D]ит[Bm],$ О[D#o],",
        " позво[A/e]ль лишь с Тобо[E7]ю идт[A]и[D][A][E7].$",
    )
    val list: MutableList<MutableList<Line>> = mutableListOf()

    val chordRegex = """\[(\w+)]""".toRegex()
    val line: MutableList<Line> = mutableListOf()

    verses.forEach { verse ->
        val chords = mutableListOf<Word>()
        val words = mutableListOf<Word>()

        verse.split(" ").forEach { word ->
            val matchResult = chordRegex.find(word)
            if (matchResult != null) {
                val extractedChord = matchResult.groupValues[1]
                chords.add(Word(text = extractedChord, isChord = true))
                words.add(
                    Word(
                        text = word.replace("[$extractedChord]", ""),
                        isChord = false,
                    )
                )
            } else {
                chords.add(Word(text = "", isChord = false))
                words.add(Word(text = word, isChord = false))
            }
        }
        line.add(Line(row = chords, isChord = true))
        line.add(Line(row = words, isChord = false))
    }

    return line
}


Your parsing logic looks fine to me. To now draw the chords above the text, you can use Text Composables inside of a Column like this:
@Composable
fun TextChordsComposable() {
    val songString = remember { "I'm foll[D]owing [G]Jesus, One st[C]ep at a time[D]" }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
    ) {
        songString.split(" ").forEach { word: String ->
            val regex = """\[(\w+)]""".toRegex()
            val matchResult = regex.find(word)

            if (matchResult != null) {
                val chord = matchResult.groupValues[1]
                val rawWord = word.replace(regex, "")
                Text(
                    text = "$chord\n$rawWord "
                )
            } else {
                Text(
                    text = "$word "
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

The output looks as follows:

If you want to position the chord according to the position of the [] in the word, you will need a more advanced parsing logic that checks whether the [] is in the beginning, middle, or end of a word.
Let me know when you publish your Onsong app on the Google Play Store :)

thank you for your answer, i have a other challenge now.
with this parser logic i can't display more than one choird:
val songString = remember { "I'm foll[D]owing [G]Jesus, One st[C]ep at a time[D][Dm][D] " }
and if the line is too long, how to automatically get to the new line:
val songString = remember { "I'm foll[D]owing [G]Jesus, One st[C]ep at a time[D] I'm foll[D]owing [G]Jesus, One st[C]ep at a time[D] I'm foll[D]owing [G]Jesus, One st[C]ep at a time[D] " }


If you want to break a Row into a new line when there are many Text Composables, you can use a FlowRow. But that is another topic. If you found my answer above useful, please consider to mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer.
